# GM thumb method not centering cropped image in Node

Tags: node.js, image, graphicsmagick

I'm using GM for node ([link](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm)) and I'm having trouble with the thumb() method.

This is my input image:

[image]

And this is my ouput image:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const gm = require('gm');

gm('./public/img/test.jpg').thumb(200, 200, './public/img/test-2.jpg', 100, function(err, data){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("Done!");
});
```

As you can see, the resulting thumbnail is not centered, is aligned to the left, is there a way to center it? It doesn't say anything in the docs:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I realized what was the problem. GM has a method called gravity that tells where will be methods applied in some of them.

So I had to add:

`.gravity('Center')` right after `gm(img)`. Like this:

```
gm('./public/img/test.jpg').gravity('Center').thumb(200, 200, './public/img/test-2.jpg', 100, function(err, data){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("Done!");
});
```